# Sort / Order Entries on select or button click

Tags: entries, forloop, ajax, ordering, sorting

I have a page on my website were I display alot of entries. Now I want those entries to be sorted by Date, Title etc. I know how to change that hard coded but I want to make it dynamic with a `<select>`. I guess I need to use Ajax for this but after a long search I still cant figure it out.

**The Select**

```
        <select>
            <option value="{% set order = "postDate asc" %}">New - Old</option>
            <option value="{% set order = "postDate desc" %}">Old - New</option>
            <option value="{% set order = "title asc" %}">A-Z</option>
            <option value="{% set order = "title desc" %}">Z-A</option>
        </select>
```

**The loop**

```
        {% set counter = 0 %}
        {% for entry in craft.entries.section('tips').order('{{ order }}') %}
            {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
            {% include 'includes/tip-blocks' %}
        {% endfor %}
```

To make the question short.

**Sort entries dynamicly through a select form. Prefer not to reload the page but, it's oke if it does.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so you can either do this through ajax or through a page reload, a page reload is going to be much easier, but you can get it to work without reloading the page...

**Reloading the page**

You can basically make it so that when a user selects an option, use jQuery to redirect to the current page and append the `<option>` value to append as a query string, so your template could look like this:

```
<select id="sortQuery">
 <option value="postDate asc">New - Old</option>
 <option value="postDate desc">Old - New</option>
 <option value="title asc">A-Z</option>
 <option value="title desc">Z-A</option>
</select>
```

Then, you can do this in your template:

```
{% set orderJs %}
  $(function(){

    $('#sortQuery').on("change", function(e){

     // Get the value from the select
     var filter = $(this).val();

     // We can use twig because we are setting this in template, if you extracted this to its own file, you would need a different means to output the page url
     document.location.href = '{{ craft.request.getUrl() }}?order=' + filter;

   });

  });
{% endset %}

{# let craft include the script to the end of our template #}
{% includeJs orderJs %}
```

Then, in your template file your code could be:

```
{% set counter = 0 %}

{# Either get the order from the query or use a default #}
{% set order = craft.request.getParam('order', 'title asc')  %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.section('tips').order(order) %}
  {% set counter = counter + 1 %}
  {% include 'includes/tip-blocks' %}
{% endfor %}
```

This should then reload the request with the query string, craft will see it and update the response accordingly. I must stress this is untested, but it should work...

**Without reloading the page**

This gets a little more complex and would involve more jQuery/Javascript than craft so I won't go into too much detail about it.

The steps are pretty much the same as above, except within the script tags (where you listen for a select change) you would make an [ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to either a html template (which contains the sorted results) or even using the [ElementApi](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) plugin to return json (from a template) which you can then iterate over in jQuery and then update your DOM accordingly.

I hope this helps get you on track!

Comment: This is all i get: `CDbCommand failed while performing the following SQL statement: SQLSTATE [ 42S22 ] : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' craft_order ' in ' order clause '` Thanks for the answer though still figuring this one out!

Comment: Sorry there was an error in the way the entries were fetched, was passing `{{ order }}` as a string when it should have just referenced the variable, I have updated my answer.

Comment: That was the last fix to it :D I'll be trying to get it without reloading now.